# Working with OPEN NFC simulator + Linux OS

Tags: android, linux, fedora, open-nfc

I'm working on an Android application which can read and write on NFC tag, and I'd like to know if I can use the simulator OPEN NFC on Linux OS (specifically fedora)?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, here is the link from open-nfc.org

http://open-nfc.org/wp/editions/linux-edition/

There is also an Android version

http://open-nfc.org/wp/editions/android/

EDIT:

> Linux Edition Requirements:
>
> Another machine running Windows to use the Connection Center and NFC Simulator.

Apparently the same applies for any build. The only NFC Simulator they provide is a win32 executable.
You can probably run it under [Wine](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Wine?rd=AndreasBierfert/Wine) though...

Comment: I already downloaded the simulator from to their official web site,and and I followed the instalation instructions, but I have a problem when running the simulator , which has .exe extension : NFCSimulator.exe

Comment: both of the links i provided above

Comment: I already downloaded the simulator from this two links but the two are one .exe extension :
http://open-nfc.org/wp/home/downloads/

Comment: [linux dl link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/open-nfc/files/Open%20NFC%204.5.1%20%2815725%29/Open%20NFC%20-%20Linux%20Edition%20v4.5.1%20%2815725%29.zip/download) [android dl link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/open-nfc/files/Open%20NFC%204.5.1%20%2815725%29/Delivery_2012-12-14_android-4.2.1_r1_OpenNFC_4.5.1.tar.gz/download) neither of which are .exe

Comment: OK ,I also have to use [the reference porting](http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_open-nfc/downloads/Open%20NFC%204.3%20beta%20%2810381%29/Docs/MAN_NFC_1104-237%20Open%20NFC%20-%20Android%20Gingerbread%202.3.3%20-%20Porting%20Guide%20v1.3.pdf/)  that allows the use of the NFC Simulator with linux OS + windows virtual machine to run the Connection Center and NFC Simulator.